# How to move files to iOS 13, 14 with libimobiledevice?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iphone, ios

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and am unable to get libimobiledevice to move files to my iPhone (iPhone Xr, running iOS 14.7.1), or to my iPod (running iOS 13.2.2).

I installed libimobiledevice with the single line command found in https://libimobiledevice.org/#get-started, i.e.:

```
sudo apt-get install usbmuxd libimobiledevice6 libimobiledevice-utils
```

This goes without any error, and then I am able to pair the phone, look at files on it, and even move files from phone to computer.

However, when I try to move files from computer to phone, it just hangs up. There's a progress bar which doesn't change, and a time estimate of "596,523 hours" no matter the size of the file being downloaded to the phone.

For comparison, with an older iPhone (running iOS 9.3.5) file transfer in both directions with libimobiledevice works perfectly.

I also tried another computer--also running Ubuntu 18.04--but I get the same issue.

This situation has been mentioned in only a couple other threads that I could find, namely:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177391/cannot-transfer-files-to-iphone-with-libimobiledevice

https://www.mail-archive.com/desktop-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg769447.html

...But when I follow the advice in these threads (basically, manually install the latest packages from GitHub), I still can't move anything from Ubuntu to iOS 13 or 14.

Successfully transferring files from a Linux computer to a phone running a recent version of iOS seems like it would be a fairly basic use-case for libimobiledevice, so I am surprised I cannot find more discussion of this problem. Appreciate any help!

(PS: One other thing I recently discovered about this problem: I technically *can* move files from the Linux machine to an iOS >12 device, but only if these files are tiny (<16kB). Anything bigger and you get the "596,523 hours" progress bar instead. So obviously that's not much practical use but maybe it helps someone guess what's going on...)